# Remove div from rss feed

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I have a plugin that adds a rating feature to my posts. This is inserted into `the_content` in a div and thus shows up in my RSS feed. I'd like to exclude that specific div (has it's own classname) from my RSS feed.
Can this be achieved by a filter? Or do I need to make a custom feed and if so, how do I remove the div then?

Cheers